# Problem with Smoothing experimental data (Savitzky-Golay & C++)?

Tags: filters

I'm trying to use Savitzky-Golay Filter to smooth experimental data. Savitzky-Golay computes $c_{n}$ in the following equation 
$$ g_{i} = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=-n_{L}}^{n_{R}} c_{n}f_{i}+n$$

According to Numerical Recipes book by William H. Press. I've bought the library. The next step to calculate $g_{0}$ which represents the smoothed data. To fulfil that, we need to convolute $c_{n}$ with $f_{i}+n$. Luckily, there is a function to do so namely "convlv()". I'm passing 17 points of the stream data ( nl = 7, nr = 7, m = 4 ). To compute $c_{n}$, I'm using "savgol()". The sample rate of the experimental data is 1KHz ( 0.001 second ). After smoothing the data, the sample rate decreased to 100Hz **WHY?**.
The unsmoothed data is

[image]
and the smoothed data is

[image]

This is my code

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include "nr3.h"
#include "ludcmp.h"
#include "savgol.h"
#include "fourier.h"
#include "convlv.h"



int main(void)
{
    std::ifstream raw_data;
    std::ofstream smoothed_data;
    std::vector<double> x;

    raw_data.open("data.txt");
    smoothed_data.open("smoothed.txt");

    VecDoub_IO ans(17);
    VecDoub_IO data(17);
    VecDoub_IO respns(17);

    const Int np(17), nl(8), nr(8), ld(0), m(4);
     savgol(respns, np, nl, nr, ld,  m);
    for (int i = 0; i < 17; ++i)
    {
    std::cout << respns[i] << " ";
    }

    if (raw_data.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "Error in open xdata file";
    }
    if (smoothed_data.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "Error in Opening xdot file";
    }
    double line(0);
    while ( raw_data >> line )
    {
        x.push_back(line);
    }


    int xdata_counter(0);

    // void convlv(VecDoub_I &data, VecDoub_I &respns, const Int isign, VecDoub_O &ans) 

    while ( xdata_counter < (x.size() - 25) )
    {
        for (int i = 8; i <= 17; ++i)
        {
            data[i] = x[xdata_counter];
            ++xdata_counter;

        }
        //four1(&data[0],data.size()/2,isign);
        convlv(data, respns, 1, ans);
        smoothed_data << ans[0] << std::endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        {
            data[i] = data[i+1];
        }
    }

    raw_data.close();
    smoothed_data.close();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a link to API documentation of that function?

Comment: @Phonon, thanks for the reply. Which function? convlv() or savgol()?

Comment: Well, whichever one unintentionally downsamples your signal. Also, adding some comments to your code would help, and removing irrelevant parts of it, too. It's not very easy to parse.